# .NET Core Add Package - Invalid Certificate

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL Ubuntu which doesn't have complete certificate chains for some sites, including NuGet.

As a consequence, I can't add or restore packages from NuGet. Is there a way to bypass it?

Example:

```
dotnet restore
```

Gets the following error:

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100/NuGet.targets(123,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [/home/pomatti/Projects/dojo-for-net/solutions/WhiteBelt/WhiteBelt.sln]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100/NuGet.targets(123,5): error :   The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. [/home/pomatti/Projects/dojo-for-net/solutions/WhiteBelt/WhiteBelt.sln]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100/NuGet.targets(123,5): error :   The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure. [/home/pomatti/Projects/dojo-for-net/solutions/WhiteBelt/WhiteBelt.sln]
```

### Update

I tried manually adding all certificates to Ubuntu but it didn't work:

1. Copied Baltimore, Microsoft and NuGet certs to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificate`
2. Executed `sudo update-ca-certificates`

Got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that runs into this problem, there is no way of bypassing the certificate validation.

My Ubuntu app was problematic for some reason. I had to reinstall it to solve the issue.

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4666

Answer (score 3):

I'm in corporate environment and met the same error. Eventually I found the solution for my case.

Initially I tried to copy root CA certificate into the same path you mentioned above, however when I run the command to update-ca-certificates, I found in the output it was looking for the path `/etc/ssl/certs/` instead of `/usr/local/share/ca-certificate`.

It's figured out after coping cert to that folder and `update-ca-certificates`.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

My problem ended up being different: WSL still, to this day, has a stupid bug where the time can get wildly off-track, especially if your computer goes to sleep. In my case, my WSL instance was two days in the past, which was breaking SSL validation.

The solution was to either fully shutdown wsl by exiting all windows then doing `wsl --shutdown` in powershell or somewhere else, or just restarting the computer. Synchronizing the clock with NIST or whomever else doesn't always work in WSL for some reason.

After you've verified the time is correct again (just do `date` within wsl) try the network commands again and see if they work (in my case it was both `apt update` and `dotnet add package`)